# iOS app shows cumulated reputation increase instead of new reputation increase

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, ios-app, achievements-dialog

After updating to **Stack Exchange's iOS app V1.6.5.1 (TestFlight)**, the reputation increase seems to always show the cumulated reputation increase whenever a specific post is upvoted.

For example, I received +10 on a post in the morning and cleared it afterwards. In the afternoon, I received another +10 on the same post, the reputation increase **should show +10**, since I've already cleared the +10 received in the morning.

However, this is not the case in the iOS app as it would show +20, which the cumulated reputation increase I received for that specific post on that day.

---

**Images to illustrate:**

I've a post upvoted 7 times and accepted. Both are accessed at the same time, **after I received 2 more upvotes**.

The app shows the cumulative rep increase for the post which shouldn't be the case:

[image: Image 1]

Meanwhile, it displays correctly on the site:

[image: Image 2]

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It doesn't, it shows just the rep increase on the site

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're seeing then. What I see on the desktop is a +X notification, and a +Y entry when I open the dropdown, where Y is the cumulative reputation increase on that post today. E.g. this notification I just got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcTYU.png . Is the behaviour in the iOS app you're seeing different than that desktop behaviour? Maybe adding a screenshot to this question would clarify the issue.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yup, what you described is the correct behavior, what I'm seeing is that the +X notification shows the cumulative rep increase on that post whenever it's upvoted. So, the 1st upvote for the day should show green +10 after I dismissed it, nothing should show (which works well). However, when I receive another upvote, it would show +20 instead of +10 which is wrong.

Comment: The bug is that the +X value also shows the cumulative value, which shouldn't be the case; only the +Y should be cumulative. In my case, both shows the cumulative value. Thanks for the idea to use +X & +Y to explain, it's much clearer :)

Comment: That clarifies things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding some details.

Fixed in 1.6.5.2.

I recently updated how achievements are fetched by the app.  Before, the achievements would come through as 50 raw items which we would merge on the client.  This resulted in different achievements from the topbar which takes 200ish achievements, merges, and displays the top 50.  Now we're getting the 50 merged events from the server and displaying them directly.

Unfortunately, we were also using the achievements API to get the unread items count, loading the achievements and looping through the unread.  Because of the way the topbar works, if you have an item with +40 reputation that's read, and it gets another +10, it shows up as +50 unread.  That was causing us to have a much higher number of unread than actual.

To solve this, I've added a new API method that just returns the topbar counts.  It should actually be a lot cheaper of a call too since we don't need to fetch the full achievement list and inbox every time the app launches.